# Target [Repository] is not instantiable while building [Controller, Service]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que ao enviar dados pelo formulário esta me retornando esse **erro**:

> BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 763: Target
>   [Igreja\Repositories\MembroRepository] is not instantiable while
>   building [Igreja\Http\Controllers\MembroController,
>   Igreja\Services\MembroService].

Já fiz uma pesquisa e as soluções que me são apresentadas estão relacionadas com `namespace`, mas já olhei varias vezes, apaguei, criei de novo etc. e o **erro** persiste. Já estou preso aqui a dois dias. Usando `Laravel 5.3` e `prettus repository 2.6`.

Segue demais documentos:

**Model** `Membro.php`

```
<?php

namespace Igreja\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\Transformable; 
use Prettus\Repository\Traits\TransformableTrait;

class Membro extends Model implements Transformable {
    use TransformableTrait;

    protected $table    = 'membros';

    protected $fillable = [
        'desde',
        'pretencoes_funcoes_id',
        'pretencoes_profissionais_id',
        'pretencoes_cursos_id'
    ]; 
}
```

**Service** `MembroService.php`

```
<?php

namespace Igreja\Services;

use Igreja\Repositories\MembroRepository; 
use Igreja\Entities\Membro;

class MembroService {
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(MembroRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
}
```

***Estrutura de pastas***

> [image: Estrutura de pastas]

Comment: Já entrei com esse comando: php artisan app:name Igreja

Comment: felipe como está a sua configuração do `composer.json`, porque eu estou perguntado: você saiu do padrão e por isso precisa registrar os `namespaces`

Comment: Virgilio,

"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "prettus/l5-repository": "^2.6",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "lord/laroute" : "2.*"
    },

Comment: eu coloquei uma resposta! dá uma olhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na chave do arquivo **`composer.json`**, inclua **`"Igreja\\": "app/"`**:

```js
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Igreja\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Na linha de código digite:

```
php composer dumpautoload
```

> **Porque tem que colocar essa configuração?**

Precisa ser registrado o novo `namespace` criado `Igreja` e sua pasta correspondente `app/` para o carregamento dessas classes.

Depois disso crie um [`ServiceProvider`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers) com o comando:

```
php artisan make:provider IgrejaServiceProvider
```

dentro dele no método *`register()`* coloque:

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(MembroRepository::class, MembroRepositoryEloquent::class);
    // as demais logo abaixo todas as classes
}
```

finalizando entre dentro da pasta `config/` arquivo `app.php` adicione no `providers` assim:

```
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

App\Providers\IgrejaServiceProvider::class
```

<sub>**Observação:** Se não quiser criar o [`ServiceProvider`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers) pode colocar no construtor `MembroRepositoryEloquent`(acredito ser a classe comum que pode ser instânciada, então, a primeira parte da solução já resolveria).</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers)
- [Service Providers - PT-br](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/5.1/providers)
- [Service Container](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/5.1/container)
- [Registering a Service Provider With the Application](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/199/registering-a-service-provider-with-the-application)

Comment: Obrigado, mas esse parametro já existe, veja como esta:

"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Igreja\\": "app/"
        }
    },

Comment: você executou o comando `php composer dumpautoload`? @felipeldnascimento

Comment: Sim. O erro persiste.

Comment: `php composer dumpautoload` dá algum erro na execução? @felipeldnascimento

Comment: @felipeldnascimento `MembroRepository` é uma `interface` ou  uma classe `abstract`???

Comment: @felipeldnascimento se `MembroRepository` é uma `interface` ou classe `abstract` tem que informar para `framework` qual classe é utilizado como instância que acredito ser no caso `MembroRepositoryEloquent`, fiz a edição na resposta adicionando os dois casos.

Comment: Novic, o problema foi resolvido fazendo o que você flw em app/Config. Obrigado !